# CSS media query position element at fixed bottom NOT relative to parent element

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, css-position

I have a filter element (`<div>`) inside a fixed positioned `<nav>` container at the top of the viewport next to some links.

On mobile devices I'd like to position this filter element at the bottom of the viewport but keep the other nav links at the top of the viewport.

However, – of course – using `bottom: 0` positions the filter element relative to the `<nav>` container and not the viewport, so it's still at the top of the viewport.

Is there any trick to position the filter element at the bottom of the viewport by ignoring/overriding the `<nav>`'s position?

My code:

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .filter {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      background: green;
      z-index: 3;
  }
}
```

Edit:

The html is

```
<nav>
    <div class='nav__links'>
      <a>Page 1</a>
      <a>Page 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class='filter'>
      <button>Category A</button>
      <button>Category B</button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I also tried a js `cloneNode` in connection with `window.matchMedia('(max-width: 500px)')` to move the filter `<div>` outside the `<nav>` and attach it to the body, but there are some issues on iOS.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Please provide the HTML for your `<nav>`. But why doesn't `position: absolute` work in this case?

Comment: The html is `<nav><div class='nav__links'> <a>Page 1</a><a>Page 2</a> </div> <div class='filter'><button>Category A</button><button> Category B</button> </div></nav>`. The ` .filter` `<div>` should stick at the bottom while scrolling so `position: absolute` is not used.

Comment: Can you please add your whole HTML, including head and body tags? The CSS looks fine, I think the problem may be in HTML meta tags